# Table view not showing data from realm database on first launch Swift

Tags: ios, realm, tableview, swift5

My goal is to display data fetched from realm database on the table view that I previously asynchronously added whenever I launch the app.

The problem is that when I first launch my app the table view doesn't show any data fetched from realm database but if I pull it to refresh the data is displayed.

Here is what I do in the following code:

1. I fetch data (contacts) from apple's contacts framework and pass them through a closure to a helper method where I:

   - Add them to realm database
   - fetch the contacts and store them in the data source array (setDataSource)
   - create the section titles for the table view

So far I made the debugging and noticed that the problem maybe with threading and concurrency, that is, on first launch the data is being added to realm asynchronously so when I fetch the contacts there's nothing to fetch.

Saying that, I haven't been able to solve the above identified problem so far because I don't know how to. I am learning to code with threading and concurrency and to use realm.

I've also seen some posts but in none of them were a similar problem.

I'd be very grateful for your help.
Thank you!

**Table view controller:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    populateTableView() // TODO: Contacts don't show up on first launch of the app after installation.
}

func populateTableView() {
    contactManager.populateDataSource(for: self)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

**Contact manager Class:**

```
let store = CNContactStore()
let dataBase = DataBase()
var contactsDataSource = [[Contact]]()
var sectionTitles = [String]()

var deletedContactsDataSource = [[Contact]]()
var sectionTitlesForDeletedContactsTable = [String]()    

func fetchUserContacts(completion: @escaping ContactsFetchingResult) {
    print("Attempting to fetch contacts today...")

    store.requestAccess(for: .contacts) { (granted, error) in
        if let errorToCatch = error {
            print("Failed to request access: ", errorToCatch)
        } else if granted {
            print("Access granted")
            let keys = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey, CNContactImageDataAvailableKey, CNContactIdentifierKey, CNContactOrganizationNameKey]
            let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys as [CNKeyDescriptor])

            do {
                try self.store.enumerateContacts(with: request, usingBlock: { (contact, stopPointerIfYouWantToStopEnumerating) in
                    completion(contact, nil)
                })
            } catch {
                completion(nil, error)
            }
        } else {
            print("Access denied")
        }
    }
}

func populateDataSource(for viewController: UIViewController?) {
    fetchUserContacts { (result, error) in
        if let errorToCatch = error {
            guard let vc = viewController else { return }
            UITableViewController.Alert.showFetchingErrorAlert(on: vc, message: errorToCatch.localizedDescription)
        } else if let contact = result {
            self.dataBase.insert(each: Contact(contact: contact, wasDeleted: false))
            self.setDataSource()
            self.setSectionTitles()
        }
    }
}

func setDataSource(from searchTerm: String = "") {
    //Not deleted contacts
    if !searching {
        contactsDataSource = formatResults(from: dataBase.fetchContacts(), using: sectionTitles)
    } else {
        setDataSourceForFilteredContacts(from: searchTerm)
    }
    //Deleted contacts
    deletedContactsDataSource = formatResults(from: dataBase.fetchDeletedContacts(), using: sectionTitlesForDeletedContactsTable)
}

func setSectionTitles() {
    sectionTitles = generateSectionTitles(from: dataBase.fetchContacts())
    sectionTitlesForDeletedContactsTable = generateSectionTitles(from: dataBase.fetchDeletedContacts())
}
```

**Database:**

```
func insert(each contact: Contact) {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(contact, update: .modified)
    }
}

func fetchContacts() -> Results<Contact> {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    return realm.objects(Contact.self).filter("wasDeleted = false").sorted(byKeyPath: "firstName", ascending: true)
}
```

Comment: What does `setupTableView`? And `reloadData` in `populateTableView` has no effect because the data are received from the database much later.

Comment: @vadian **setupTableView** is just method to set table view's background and define **isEditing** property. 

**populateTableView** is called also in the refresh method that's why I **reloadData** there but actually just fixed it.

Comment: Move `reloadData` from `populateTableView` into `populateDataSource` after the line `self.setSectionTitles()`

Comment: @vadian **populateDataSource** is a method from ContactManager class and this class doesn't inherit from UITableViewController. I see that I have the view controller (tableviewcontroller) as a parameter passed to the method, but is that a good practice?

Comment: Then you need to add a completion handler. `requestAccess` in `fetchUserContacts` works asynchronously.

Comment: @vadian If you look closely there's already a completion handler in the **requestAccess** call

Comment: Yes, but `reloadData()` is called much earlier than the completion handler. I just saw the `viewController` parameter. Call `viewController.tableView.reloadData()` after `self.setSectionTitles()` and the parameter type must be `UITableViewController` or a protocol type which contains the `tableView` instance.

Comment: @vadian it's raising an exception because I am trying to reloadData on a background  thread. UI may only be updated on the main thread.

Comment: I deleted my answer because the question does not contain enough information to suggest a reliable solution. It's clearly an asynchronous issue.

Comment: Well. I can add more information than. I added only added this so that the question doesn't get to big.

Comment: This is confusing `func populateDataSource(for viewController: UIViewController?` as you are passing in a viewController but then never do anything with it. Also, the code is very convoluted and could be greatly simplified. You don't need to load data on a background thread and your using asynchronous completion handlers when none is needed. I would suggest commenting all of that code and in your viewDidLoad method do two things 1) populate the tableView dataSource from Realm 2) tableView.reloadData and see if it works. If not then something else is wrong unrelated to the code in the question.

Comment: @Jay got it. But either way the **enumerateContacts** method has an asynchronous block where I get the user's contacts that I requested. I got rid of the completion blocks and replaced it with dataBase.insert() method. Even if I do as you suggested at 1) I need to populate the database first and be able to then fetch this data.

Comment: *we* don't know what `enumerateContacts` does or why you're doing that. How about `self.myTableViewDataSourceResults = realm.objects(ContactClass.self).filter("whatever filter you want")` to populate the dataSource in your viewDidLoad method. You don't need `dataBase.insert() ` when you are reading data. you would only need that when writing so it would be unrelated to the question about populating a tableView.

Comment: Also, *Even if I do as you suggested at 1) I need to populate the database first and be able to then fetch this data.* is backwards. You fetch the data from Realm which populates your tableView datasource, then reload your tableView.

Comment: @Jay **enumerateContacts** is a method from CNContactStore that enables me to request the data (user's contacts) that I want to store in the database and then read them from the database to display on table view. So I need to have data in my database in the first place so that I can read and display it on table view. On the question I describe what I did and what may be the problem.

Comment: I really think you're approaching this task in an overly complex way - perhaps that's on purpose to further your knowledge? If you're just learning to code, a pro tip is: simpler is better - the more complex you make something, the higher the chances are it will break and it's also a lot harder to maintain. The solution is to read the contacts, iterate over them and create realm objects for each one and add them to a Results var that's used as the dataSource for your tableView. Reload the tableview then realm.write those objects. You don't need threading or concurrency for any of the process.

Comment: @Jay that's exactly the purpose. And thank you very much for the tip I will definitely take in account.